# Midpoints and other constraints in triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I'm trying to solve this problem:

[image]

I can intuitively observe that $\angle IFH = 2\angle NMH$, but don't know how to prove it.

I extended segment $NM$ until it intersects the (extended) segment $IF.$ Let's call the intersection point $P.$

If I could prove that newly created triangle FMP is isosceles $(FM = FP)$, then this would prove that $\angle IFH = 2\angle NMH. $

I even did a simulation in Fusion 360 ([video here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV5Me.jpg)) and it's interesting to see how the constraints work together to keep $FM = FP.$

Answer (score 3):

Let $K$ be a point on $IH$ such that $FK\parallel MN.$

[image]
$$\frac{HM}{MF}=\frac{HN}{NK}\implies \frac{a+b}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\implies ad+bd=bc .$$

We can manipulate the above expression to show,$$\frac{a}{a+2b}=\frac{c-d}{c+d}\implies \frac{FI}{FH}=\frac{IK}{HK}$$
By the converse of [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20geometry%2C%20the%20angle%20bisector,two%20sides%20of%20the%20triangle.),
$$\angle KFI=\angle KFH=\alpha \implies  \angle IFH=2\alpha.$$

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! What did you use for the drawing? It looks lovely.

Comment: I usually make use of [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry?lang=en) :)

Comment: @SathvikAcharya you may also be interested in looking at my solution. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was just going through this question and I could see a simple solution that I would like to share.

[image]

If $Q$ is the midpoint of $FH$, $MQ = \frac{GH}{2}$. Also by midpoint theorem, $NQ \parallel IF$ and $NQ = \frac{IF}{2} = \frac{GH}{2}$.

As $MQ = NQ, \angle IFH = \angle NQH = 2 \alpha$

Comment: Why MQ=GH/2 ?..

Comment: @ACB $FH = FM + MG + GH = 2 FM + GH$ (as $FM = MG$). So, $FQ = FM + \frac{GH}{2}$

Comment: I must say, a clever observation!

Comment: The construction is logical and in this case extremely helpful :)

Comment: @SathvikAcharya thanks, that's why we love geometry :) sometimes I take pages to solve a problem and someone draws a line and the solution turns into a few lines...

Answer (score 2):

Rotate $\triangle FHI$ by $180^\circ$ about the side-midpoint $N$. Let the images of $F,M,G$ be $F', M', G'$ respectively.

[image]

After the rotation, $FHF'I$ is a parallelogram and $FH\parallel IF'$.

Join $FG'$, the segment $FG'$ split $\angle IFH$ into

$$\angle IFH = \angle IFG' + \angle G'FH.$$

Since lengths $FM=MG = M'G'$, $FMM'G$ is also a parallelogram and $FG' \parallel MN$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\angle G'FH &= \angle NMH &&(\text{corresponding angles, }FG'\parallel MN)\\
 &= \alpha ^\circ
\end{align*}$$

Since lengths $FI=GH=IG'$, $\triangle FG'I$ is isosceles, and its base angles are equal:

$$\begin{align*}
\angle IFG' &= \angle IG'F &&(\text{base angles})\\
&= \angle G'FH &&(\text{alternate angles, }FH\parallel IF')\\
&= \alpha^\circ
\end{align*}$$

Together,

$$\angle IFH = \angle IFG' + \angle G'FH = 2\alpha^\circ$$

Comment: I love this demonstration, it was very intuitive - once I had the construction drawn.

Comment: PS. Added an image illustrating your demonstration, hope that's ok. The source "code": https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/gbm23t9g

Comment: Thanks for the diagram @CristianDiaconescu